# pygame, how do you get coordinates of a graphic?

Tags: python, graph, pygame, coordinates, python-3.3

I am trying to get my green square to detect the collision with the blue
square, however, I don't know how to construct the if statement that makes it so that it collides as soon as it comes in contact.

If I make it so that the position of **rect1** is >= 200,100
it would detect the collision if crossed beyond the blue square too
[image: g]

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys
import time
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) #Display

running = True
randomList = ("Hello", "Hi", "Why", "Die", "Billy Nye")
#Colors
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

#Time variables
time = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Movement Variables
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 200
lead_x1 = 200
lead_y1 = 100
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
position = (200,100)

#Running MAIN Loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(white)
    rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [lead_x,lead_y, 50, 50])
    rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x1,lead_y1, 50 ,50])
    pygame.display.update()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = -10
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 10
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_change = -10
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_change = 10

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y_change = 0
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y_change = 0

    if lead_x == lead_x1 and lead_y == lead_y1:
        print (random.choice(randomList))


    lead_x += x_change
    lead_y += y_change
    time.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collision response](http://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html)

```
    rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [lead_x,lead_y, 50, 50])
    rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, [lead_x1,lead_y1, 50 ,50])
    if rect2.colliderect(rect1):
        print("BOOM!")
```

If you want the coordinates:

```
print(rect2.left,rect2.right,rect2.top,rect2.bottom)
```

These are the attributes you can use taken from [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> x,y
>   top, left, bottom, right
>   topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
>   midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
>   center, centerx, centery
>   size, width, height
>   w,h

Comment: Wow that's so helpful, thank you. I didn't know such a function existed,

Comment: however would there be a way of measuring the exact values of each point of the blue rectangle

Comment: You want to see if the object is within a certain area? Or just get it's coordinates?